# Lua function needs to be assigned to variable

Tags: function, variables, lua

I have been trying to learn some lua recently, and I came across something I didn't understand with functions today, the code below didn't work

```
function iter()
  local i=0
  return function() print(i); i=i+1; end
end

iter()
iter()
```

I had to assign a variable to my function iter() and then call the variable before it would run:

```
function iter()
  local i=0
  return function() print(i); i=i+1; end
end

it=iter()
it()
it()
```

can anyone clarify why that is?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code did work (also, for the future, please remember to always clarify what "not working" means). It just returns the function that does the increment. You might benefit from a look at https://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html

Comment: oh thanks, ill look at that. also its my first time on here, so ill make sure to be more specefic next time :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, functions are just values. Your outer function is assigned to the variable `iter`. That function returns an anonymous function. ("Anonymous" just means you did not give the function a name before returning it.)

Secondly, an argument list in parentheses is basically an operator that calls a function (unless it's in a function declaration). When you use that operator, the function runs and the expression results in the return value.

In the statement `iter()`, you call a function and ignore its return value, so you never get to see the inner function run.

In the statement `it = iter()`, you end up with a named function called `it`. Every time you call it, it increments the `i` variable from inside the `iter` call that created it.

As a side note, it would be legal to say `iter()()` to immediately call the returned function. This wouldn't actually be useful in your case, because each call to `iter` returns a fresh closure with `i` starting at zero.

Comment: thanks alot! answered my question and i learned abit more about functions :)